# Не выходит функция .innerHTML

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Привет</title>
        <script src="java.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <H1 id="rer">hello</H1>
    </body>
</html>
```

И в `js`:

```
document.getElementById('rer').innerHTML='Помогите пожалуйста';
```

Comment: Попробуйте подключить скрипт перед закрывающимся `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт должен быть подключен после тех элементов, к которым он обращается:

```
<H1 id="rer">hello</H1>
<script src="java.js"></script>
```

Другой вариант — ждать загрузки документа и только потом что-то делать:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('rer').innerHTML='Помогите пожалуйста';
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
#rer
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Привет</title>
        <script src="java.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <H1 id="rer" onclick="this.innerHTML='Помогите пожалуйста Игорь'" title="нажмите">НАЖМИТЕ</H1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Перед закрывающимся body вставьте <script src="javascript/java.js"></script> 
 где src="где находится ваш .js"

Comment: И зачем тогда ему переносить в конец файл, если Вы заинлайнили (плохо, очень плохо) код?

Comment: свой код вставьте в window.onload = function(){var abc = document.getElementById('rer');   abc.innerHTML='Помогите пожалуйста';};

Comment: Зачем ждать `window.onload`?

Comment: В конце body ставят уже последние лет 5 . с onclick просто шутка

Comment: Скрипт не может нормально работать пока не загружен DOM

Comment: Иначе возможна потеря контекста..

Comment: Но ведь DOM к моменту вызова `window.onload` уже давно построен, зачем жать? И какой контекст может быть потерян?

Comment: Событие срабатывает на window.onload когда??? в момент полной загрузки DOM а не на давно уже построен..

Comment: Вообще-то срабатывает оно когда загружено всё - картинки, iframe, etc.

Comment: А это разве не полная загрузка DOM . как вы будете работать с картинкой если она не загрузилась . с чем работать скрипту к примеру если он автоматом выставляет размер этой картинки . это разве не потеря контекста ???

Comment: Я бессилен; идите учить матчасть, а потом других учить.

Answer (score -4):

Я так полагаю у вас просто не верно подключен js файл. Какая ошибка у вас в консоли? Смотрите, всё работает: [ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pinkyrabbit/gpydyxkg/)

```html
<body>
     <script>document.getElementById('rer').innerHTML='Помогите пожалуйста';</script>
     <H1 id="rer">hello</H1>
</body>
```

Comment: Не вводите в заблуждение новичков, фиддл оборачивается в `window.onload`, а тут - нет.

Comment: @Other, там скрипт в конце body, даже если onload отключить.